# How can I create an observable collection from LINQ that was written to create an array?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code that creates an Array:

```
private ParamViewModel[] _mode;
public ParamViewModel[] Mode{ get => _mode; set => SetProperty(ref _mode, value); }

Mode = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MO))
   .Cast<MO>()
   .Select(x => new ParamViewModel { Id = (int)x, Name = x.Text() })
   .ToArray();
```

What I need is to create `ListOfModes`

```
    private ObservableCollection<ParamViewModel> _listOfModes;
    public ObservableCollection<ParamViewModel> ListOfModes{
        get => _listOfModes;
        set => SetProperty(ref _listOfModes, value);
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to have this as a `ListOfModes` ObservableCollection instead of an array.

Is there a way that I can do this without just listing out each element of the array and doing multiple adds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` provides the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) `ObservableCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` which allows to initialize a new collection based on an existing enumerable.

So

```
ObservableCollection<ParamViewModel> ListOfModes
    = new ObservableCollection<ParamViewModel>(
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(MO))
            .Cast<MO>()
            .Select(x => new ParamViewModel { Id = (int)x, Name = x.Text() }));
```

initializes the collection directly from your LINQ statement.

In spite of that: Are you really sure, an ObservableCollection is required here? Since the enumeration values will not change there are no needs of notifications and a simple list or an array would be totally enough.